# Where flutter project stores android application name?

Tags: flutter

How can I change if Flutter project an aplication name, which Android displays in `App Info`?

Here is a sample picture with Android's app name.

Obviously it is not the same which is defined in the `pubspeck.yaml` file.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the file in location `Android/app/src/main/android manifest.xml`

In that file find the application tag and its android label property which looks like

```
 <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="Hello World"<!-- Change this to the name you want --!>
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

Change the android:label property and then delete and re install the app